# Invalid regular expression: //: Range out of order in character class with react okta js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, okta

I am having .NET MVC application. Inside a CSHTML view I am referring below JS from OKTA CDN here,

https://global.oktacdn.com/okta-signin-widget/5.7.2/js/okta-sign-in.min.js

using below code,

```
<script src="https://global.oktacdn.com/okta-signin-widget/5.7.2/js/okta-sign-in.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If I refer CDN directly it's working fine. But if i download that file and keep it in wwwroot and refer it, it's not working.

using below code,

```
<script src="~/scripts/okta/okta-sign-in.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

below is the screenshot of console,

[image]

can anyone help me on this? it seems it is unable to recognize RegExp but how i can fix it?

Comment: The file seems not to have the correct character encoding.  Probably “saved it wrong” when you downloaded it.

Comment: I think it is not "saved wrong" but the browser "opens it wrong" when loading it from the local disk.

Answer (score 1):

To me, this looks like [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). The server does not declare this file as encoded in utf-8, so your browser assumes some other encoding (iso-8859-15, for example). Try adding `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` to the header of your webpage!

Comment: Tested by adding the charset metatag. still same.

Comment: Then maybe James was right in his [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970150/invalid-regular-expression-range-out-of-order-in-character-class-with-react/67970266?noredirect=1#comment120137461_67970150). Unfortunately, I do not know how to fix that.

Comment: It worked if save file directly as js file by right click in chrome instead of copy pasting explictly.

Answer (score 1):

It worked if save file directly as js file by right click in chrome instead of copy pasting explictly